# Convert mysql query to zf2 using subquery

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I'm want to convert this mysql query (`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM practice_details  LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5) a ORDER BY practice_name ASC`) into zend framework 2, but don't know how to convert. I am newbie.

Thanks you

Comment: What have you done? you can learn about the last version of ZendDb in https://zendframework.github.io/zend-db/

Answer (score 0):

2 steps :

first : write the sub select `SELECT * FROM practice_details  LIMIT 6 OFFSET 5`

```
$subselect = new Select();
$subselect->from('practice_details')->limit(6)->offset(5);`
```

then : write the select

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from(['a' => $subselect])->order('practice_name ASC');
```